# Looking for name of an 80's movie or series about young people on a spaceship getting sucked into a black hole?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Can't seem to remember the name of this movie, but I saw it as a child, and also read a picture book about it so it must have been franchised!

It was an obvious star wars rip off, with two or more young protagonists, male and female, some robot type things,  alien characters, and a ship that would look almost steampunkish by today's standards.

I'm vague on the plot details, but they're somehow abandoned in space and always needing to repair the spaceship, and at one point are at risk of getting sucked into a blackhole or wormhole.

It's not Disney's The Black Hole though. I looked it up cause it seemed to be the most likely candidate, but the feel of the movie I'm looking for was more fantasy than science fiction...more the Labyrinth sort of feel than Space Odyssey...in fact, the aliens and robots seemed to be influenced by Jim Henson.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/star-wars/17294/11-films-and-tv-shows-that-tried-to-be-star-wars

Comment: When were you a child? Do you remember enough to tell if it was about contemporary with the time you watched it, or if it seemed to be older?

Comment: Or would have been a late 70's or 80's movie...it was out at the same time as the first 3 star wars movies.

Comment: Were there any adults? And just checking it wasn't Lost in Space.

Comment: Another question--when you say "young" protagonists, do you remember about how young? preteen, teen, 20s? Were both about the same age?

Comment: They were young adults, part of the ships crew. I don't recall adults, the story was more about how the they were on their own at risk of getting sucked into the black hole.

Comment: I remember _The Day After Tomorrow_ that featured a spaceship sucked into a black hole, and was made as a pilot for a series (so it may have had a "series" feel) and it was produced by Gerry "Thunderbirds" Anderson (which may account for the "muppets" feel), but it was made in 1975, and it featured adults such as Brian Blessed, so that's probably not it.

Comment: Any chance of "The black hole"?